# HDBC ODBC MySQL - query only fails when compiled

Tags: mysql, haskell, odbc, hdbc

My program runs with runghc but the same program consistently fails when compiled with error "Lost connection to MySQL server during query".  The fail is not associated with a long running query (it is a CREATE VIEW on a small table).
There is nothing in the MySQL error-log, and log_warnings=1.
Environment - ubuntu (13.04 ;-), local database)

Comment: Try setting log_warnings=2 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-warnings).  What OS, what version of ghc? Can you reduce your code to a simple example that still exhibits the problem and post that code?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.
I have a very simple example that fails: http://pastebin.com/9vrStfs7
I switched from HDBC.ODBC to HDBC.MySQL, but the problem stays.
I switched to use network access 9on loopback i/f), same problem but now I can see the traffic!
I set log_warnings=2, No new messages in the log file, however I found in /var/log/mysql/error.log the following: "[Warning] Aborted connection 243 to db: (Got an error reading communication packets)"
Also, the tshark pkt trace shows the client disconnects before the server responds (about 200mS). With runghc the server response is at 300 mS

Comment: Do you know how you set the MySQL client server response timeout?

Comment: Does calling [withRTSSignalsBlocked](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HDBC-mysql/0.6.6.1/doc/html/Database-HDBC-MySQL.html#v:withRTSSignalsBlocked) make a difference?

I guess runghc uses non-threaded runtime and your compiled program uses threaded runtime.

Comment: @snak - bingo! - withRTSSignalsBlocked  fixes it - though nowhere do I explicitly call for threaded RT.  In fact, the ghc command line I used (ghc Test.hs) has to be changed to 'ghc -threaded Test.hs' to get the code using withRTSSignalsBlocked to compile!  I'd say the documentation leavses something to be desired.  Hopefully the next novice will find this thread.....

Answer (score 3):

HDBC.ODBC *must* use 'withRTSSignalsBlocked' to protect all database access actions, or risk random failures such as I describe.  This was effectively confirmed by the author of the library.

Comment: I wrapped a [**`Database.HDBC.ODBC`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-odbc-2.2.3.0/docs/Database-HDBC-ODBC.html) connection & query in [**`withRTSSignalsBlocked`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-mysql-0.6.5.1/docs/Database-HDBC-MySQL.html#v:withRTSSignalsBlocked) from the [**`Database.HDBC.MySql`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC-mysql-0.6.5.1/docs/Database-HDBC-MySQL.html) and the erratic runtime behaviour ***vanished!***